# How to convert SASS (not SCSS) to CSS with grunt?

Tags: css, command-line, sass, gruntjs

I want to convert the indented SASS syntax to CSS with grunt. I am able to use the [grunt-contrib-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-sass) plugin to convert the SCSS syntax to CSS but I am looking for a plugin to convert the indented SASS syntax.

```
sass: {
  development: {
    files: {
      "assets/css/main.css": "assets/scss/main.scss"
    }
  }
},
```

EDIT: See above for how I am currently using the plugin in my Gruntfile. I've tried changing the file extension from `.scss` to `.sass`.

Comment: Does that plugin not also work for the braceless style?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work, did you test to see if it doesn't work before asking?

Comment: @minitech No, it didn't work unfortunately..

Comment: @cimmanon Ofcourse, I tried googling for a good hour before resorting to post on here.

Comment: @SajadTorkamani it should ideally work. 
Does it give any error. 
Try running grunt sass --debug --verbose and see if you can find anything there